# Connecting to SQL Server Express from within Docker Container gives an error occurred evaluating the password

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am trying to run a docker container from the Microsoft SQL Server Express image (https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express/)

For example I've tried the following commands (I'll use the -d flag once I've got it working)

```
docker run -it -p 1433:1433 -e SA_PASSWORD=Mfp_4871nJUj_1-23H -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y --name to_delete_1 microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express powershell.exe
docker run -it -p 1433:1433 -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Mfp_4871nJUj_1-23H' -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' --name to_delete_1 microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express powershell.exe
```

(not the real password - I've tried many passwords since one of the suggestions for fixing the error I see below is to ensure that the password meets Microsoft's password policy. However for all passwords I get the same error)

I've also tried lower case sa_password

However, each time I try to connect with the sa account from within the container using any of

```
sqlcmd -U sa -P Mfp_4871nJUj_1-23H
sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Mfp_4871nJUj_1-23H
sqlcmd -S localhost\sqlexpress -U sa -P Mfp_4871nJUj_1-23H
sqlcmd -U sa
sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa
sqlcmd -S localhost\sqlexpress -U sa
```

(entering password for last 3)

I get

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'..
```

Looking at the SQL Server logs it shows

```
2017-03-13 21:25:52.32 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.
2017-03-13 21:25:52.32 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 172.22.251.6]
```

The main advice is to ensure the password meets SQL Server's password criteria but I think all of the passwords I've tried do.

I run Docker on Windows 10 Enterprise (build 14393.693).
I have Docker for Windows Version 17.03.0-ce-win1 (10300).

What do I need to do to be able to connect to SQL Server from within the container using the microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express Docker imamge?

Thanks

Comment: That error basically means that the login is disabled *and* the password is incorrect.

Comment: If the password is incorrect, then it sounds like it's not being set when I create the container, since I copy the same password between the "docker run" command and the "sqlcmd" command. If this is true, am I using the wrong docker command when running the container?

Comment: I'm not sure, not tried to run SQL Server in a container yet. The page you linked gives an example command line though - try that. Worth noting that `sa_password` is in lower case in the example.

Comment: Different help pages give different cases for sa_password. Ultimately the following command worked.

docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e 'sa_password=<my_password>' -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y'

Originally I had a docker error being masked as the mssql-server-windows-express image runs a startup script from the top-level folder and I changed the working directory in my Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you ever found the answer to this question. I have not tried connecting to the database from within the container, but I have connected to it from SSMS from outside the container. The key for me was to **specify the password in double quotes** in the original command. The final command looked like this:

```
docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password="useComplexPasswordHere" -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
```

I was then able to connect to it through SSMS. Get the IP address from the docker container using:

```
docker inspect
```

Then log in to the database through SSMS like this:

[SSMS Login info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l20Oj.png)

Comment: Had the same issue when connecting to MSSQL from within a Docker container. Once I used the double quotes it worked fine. Thx.